Is there a difference in rendering Matplotlib image (heatmaps) in Jupyter notebook vs running in Python script (terminal)?
I have an NxN symmetric matrix from a csv file that I want to visualize using a heatmap with colorbar. The values consist of 0 to 1, and possibly NaNs as well. I used the following line of code to create a heatmap & save it as a png file with dpi = 300:
def draw_heatmap(...):
        vmin = np.nanmin(matrix)  # Smallest value in the matrix (ignoring NaNs)
        vmax = np.nanmax(matrix)  # Largest value in the matrix 
        
        # Mask NaN values for coloring
        masked_matrix = np.ma.masked_invalid(matrix)

        # Define a colormap
        cmap = plt.cm.RdBu_r  # Red to Blue colormap
        cmap.set_bad(color='gray')  # Set NaN values to appear in gray
        
        # Plot heatmap
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8)) 
        heatmap = ax.imshow(masked_matrix, cmap=cmap, origin='upper', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
        ....
        plt.savefig(output_file, format='png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')

When I ran draw_heatmap in Jupyter (VSCode) and in terminal as a .py script, I obtained 2 completely different heatmaps. They are not identical as I would have expected. The following are there differences:

The diagonals in Jupyter version was correctly set to 1 (red), while in the py script, the diagonals were all white.
The Jupyter produced a 24MB size png file while the py script only 4.2MB png file.

What could be the reason for this and how will I make my py script return files/images consistent with the output in my Jupyter notebook?
Edited with the png outputs:
Can't post the data here since it's huge (~5GB). Not sure if it's even worth looking. But just some notes, I checked the output in both runs (Jupyter VSCode vs terminal py script) and the matrices are identical. The png output for both are linked here as follows:
Jupyter png output (~25MB) using matplotlib=3.1.3 with Python 3.6.13: https://ibb.co/WxjLRFz
Terminal output (~4MB) using matplotlib=3.9.2 with Python 3.9.20: https://ibb.co/qDWQdf0

Have you verified that they are using the same version of matplotlib? What other differences exist between the two codes? Is the only difference that the jupyter code is separated into cells while the python script is not?

Yeah forgot to check but they have different versions (also Python dependencies). For my Jupyter notebook, it uses matplotlib=3.1.3 with Python 3.6.13 whereas my terminal uses matplotlib=3.9.2 with Python 3.9.20. Do you think thee versions would have a significant effect?

I haven't tested it, but it is possible. Is there any reason not to update the matplotlib you're using in Jupyter to a newer version?

without seeing an example of what you are trying to plot, it is hard to know if there is a bug or which version of Matplotlib is correct.  Fake some data and post it.

Hi @JodyKlymak edited the post to reflect your query re my post. thanks!

"The diagonals in Jupyter version was correctly set to 1 (red), while in the py script, the diagonals were all white." I've looked into the image from the script and I have NOT seen a white diagonal… Could you please explain the problem any better? TY

hi @gboffi edited the links now. i believed i interchanged the links. if u can see the diagonals now from the script, you'll see white instead of red. I'm looking rn at making both system (Jupyter & terminal conda) have the same version of matplotlib but it is difficult since there are a lot of incompatibilities atm. not sure how to go about this atm

I meant fake what is being plotted in the matrix.  For instance how large is matrix?  You may want to read https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_antialiasing.html

Based on your images, you do not have anywhere near enough resolution to resolve each of those dots.  Your figure is 3_000 pixels wide, and your matrix has 16_000 entries.  You are going to be aliasing the image.
